How to determine the correct Microsoft Edge WebDriver version for a given Edge browser version
I'm trying to match the correct version of the Microsoft Edge WebDriver with the installed version of the Microsoft Edge browser on my Debian system. The version numbers between the browser and the driver don't always align, making it confusing to determine which driver version to use. Sometimes the WebDriver has a version number that the browser doesn't have, or vice versa.
I tried installing a WebDriver with the same version number as the browser, but this doesn't seem to be the best solution. For instance, I currently have version 123.0.2420.53 of both the browser and the driver, and it works fine. However, I can't rely on this approach every time as the versions don't always match.
Here's my current process for installation:

Visit https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/ to see the list of available WebDriver versions.
Run sudo apt list -a microsoft-edge-stable to find the latest browser release.
Look for an exact version match, if available.

However, this method is cumbersome and unreliable, especially when the latest WebDriver and browser versions do not match, causing version errors. How can I accurately determine the correct WebDriver version for my installed Edge browser version? Is there a more systematic way to handle this?
Any guidance or resources would be appreciated!

Might as well take a look at the newly released Selenium Manager. It features "Automated driver management", which will help you determine the correct driver version based on the browser version you have.
What's more important is you don't need extra configuration since it is shipped out of the box with each Selenium release as of version 4.6.

"What's more important is you don't need extra configuration since it is shipped out of the box with each Selenium release"
Oh Good now i have a reason to accept this as solution after checking i see similar method done with my conf guess i will keep to my conf (not that long). Thanks.
